# How to count the number of words in a Microsoft Excel file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, word-count

I need to count the total number of words in a **MS Excel** file. Usually, in MS Word or PowerPoint, it's either shown at the status bar or properties window. But in Excel, it's neither given anywhere.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Cut and paste to another program? Export to CVS and pipe though wc ?

Comment: What do you define as a word in an Excel file?  Just normal words in cells containing text?  Is a numerical value a word?  How do you equate a formula to a word count?  Do you need to count words in macros?  Do you apply the same minimum character length rules as in text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a macro for this:

Press ALT + F11 and Enter the below code.

Then Select the whole sheet run the Macro for a word count.
You cna also Just select  a section and Word Count Just that section.

```
Sub CountWords()
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim CellCount As Long
Dim TotalWords As Long
Dim NumWords As Integer
Dim Raw As String

Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveWindow.Selection.Address)
TotalWords = 0
For CellCount = 1 To MyRange.Cells.Count
If Not MyRange.Cells(CellCount).HasFormula Then
Raw = MyRange.Cells(CellCount).Value
Raw = Trim(Raw)
If Len(Raw) > 0 Then
NumWords = 1
Else
NumWords = 0
End If
While InStr(Raw, " ") > 0
Raw = Mid(Raw, InStr(Raw, " "))
Raw = Trim(Raw)
NumWords = NumWords + 1
Wend
TotalWords = TotalWords + NumWords
End If
Next CellCount
MsgBox "There are " & TotalWords & " words in the selection."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a formula like this:

```
=LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3," ",""))+1
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Not a bad result... Just needs some kind of `IF` test for empty cells, which currently count as one word.

Comment: This counts the words in a single cell.  OP asked for the count of words in the whole workbook.

Comment: Use a formula like this: `=SUM(IF(LEN(TRIM(A1:B5))=0,0,LEN(TRIM(A1:B5))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:B5," ",""))+1))`. Then press Shift + Ctrl + Enter keys simultaneously to get the result